# Zone in Bind9 successfully loaded. How to debug? Ubuntu

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ubuntu-18.04

I am new to this SysAdmin-things.

I installed Bind9 (`apt-get install bind9`) on Ubuntu Server 18. I configured forwarding, setup the zone. But it does not work.

The log says that the new zone is up.

When I ping or host `ns.ubuntu.local` it says: `ping: ns.ubuntu.local: Temporary failure in name resolution`

How can I find out, what I am missing?

Log:

```
Mär 11 08:18:42 server named[4201]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 21
Mär 11 08:18:42 server named[4201]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Mär 11 08:18:42 server named[4201]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Mär 11 08:18:42 server named[4201]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Mär 11 08:18:42 server named[4201]: zone ubuntu.local/IN: loaded serial 1
Mär 11 08:18:42 server named[4201]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Mär 11 08:18:42 server named[4201]: all zones loaded
```

My `named.conf.options`

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        forwarders {
            8.8.8.8;
            8.8.4.4;
        };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        listen-on { any; };
        allow-query { any; };
        recursion yes;
        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

My `named-conf.local`

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//
zone "ubuntu.local" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.ubuntu.local";
};

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
```

My `zones/db.ubuntu.local`

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.ubuntu.local. root.ubuntu.local. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.ubuntu.local.
ns      IN      A       192.168.2.10
www     IN      A       102.168.2.10
```

Comment: Are you doing this ping test from the server running bind? What does /etc/resolv.conf say? What happens if you do `dig @192.168.2.10 ns.ubuntu.local`?

Comment: Yes, on the server running bind. The resolv.conf says `nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0` what does it mean?

Comment: by the way: the forwarding to Google's nameservers doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact that you mentioned the name server is set to 127.0.0.53 in your `/etc/resolv.conf`, it would imply that systemd is handling the name resolution for you.  For a quick break down of what that line means, `name server 127.0.0.53` means to use the name server that is listening on that IP address, in this case it is systemd-resolved.  The `options edns0` mean to support extended DNS options allowing for larger UDP packet sizes, nothing you need to worry about here.

There are two possible fixes for this.  The first is to fix systemd-resolved so it's pointing to your instance of Bind9 running on your server.  You can do this by either a) editing /etc/systemd/resolved.conf so it says something similar to this:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.1
```

It probably has `8.8.8.8` in there. Or b) configure a systemd-resolved configuration file in `/etc/systemd/network/` with a `.network` extension.  Create a file named something like `50-mydns.network` and in it put:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0 # Your interface name

[Network]
DNS=127.0.0.1
```

If you're not sure of the interface, you can always do `systemd-resolve --status` and it should list it there. Once either of those options have been done, restart systemd-resolved using:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`.
```

The second option is to disable systemd-resolved and install resolvconf doing the following:

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
sudo apt install resolvconf
```

Then look at `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and update the nameserver line to `nameserver 127.0.0.1`.  Once that is done, you can restart resolvconf using:

```
sudo systemctl restart resolvconf
```

After either of those options, you should see your `/etc/resolv.conf` now has your name servers as defined in the configurations, and your DNS lookups should use your local bind.  You didn't mention in the comment if the `dig` command worked, but I will assume they did.

Comment: I do not get why it would be 127.0.0.53. Why the 53? I thought the resolv.conf specifies search domains. Okay, localhost makes sense then. But why .53?

Comment: I'd say it was somebody trying to be smart.  UDP/TCP port 53 is the port DNS run over, so they probably figured it'd be obvious if they used 127.0.0.53 for a local resolver.  Keeping in mind that 127.0.0.1 -> 127.255.255.255 is all local host, it makes sense in an odd way.  Most people know that 127.0.0.1 is the internal IP for the local computer, but not many know the scope is actually 127.0.0.0/8, so making a listener run on that specific IP won't cause a conflict if you want to start your own DNS server.